# Grid based color changing puzzle

Tags: logic-grid, puzzle-identification, lights-out

I am trying to identify the minigame used in the game Fontanero (the code for it is [here](https://github.com/whoozle/fontanero/blob/master/minigame.js)).  It consists of a 3x3 grid of squares, and each square is red or green.  You can click on a square to invert the color of every square in the row and column of the square you clicked on.  The goal of the game is to turn all of the squares a certain color.  For example, if the board started like this:

```
 --- --- ---
| r | g | r |
 --- --- ---
| g | g | g |
 --- --- ---
| r | g | r |
 --- --- ---
```

and you clicked on the top left square, it would become this:

```
 --- --- ---
| g | r | g |
 --- --- ---
| r | g | g |
 --- --- ---
| g | g | r |
 --- --- ---
```

I am looking for the name of this game.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Its called "Lights Off" http://www.goobix.com/games/lights-off/

Comment: @Anurag It's not. In lights off (or out) clicking on a square changes the state of the adjacent squares, not the line an column.

Comment: may be this rule fit in this case on the rules page of this game, "clicking on a square also switches the state of its North, South, East and West neighbors"

Comment: I don't think there are any specific names. I don't know any for the entire row and column except the board game Orthello, which requires you to PLACE the tile to flip others. As for flipping it and its neighbours there are many versions of this with different names; flip-it, reversi and there was even an Egyptian Yoshi version of one of the Mario party games for DS!

Comment: This variant of [Lights Out](https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/lomath.htm#alientiles) is called "Alien Tiles", though that normally cycles through four colours instead of just two.

Comment: To know more about solving this game, see the previous questions [Counter Flipping](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50032/counter-flipping) and [Turn on all squares](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52183/turn-on-all-squares).

Comment: @JaapScherphuis The turn on all squares question is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Oh come on guys, who's downvoting this? It's a perfectly reasonable thing to ask. Jeez.

Answer (score 2):

I'm typing this "answer" because it seems the question was answered in the comments but still remains as "open question" on PuzzlingSE.

[Jaap Scherphuis](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20814/jaap-scherphuis]) answered this as

> This variant of [Lights Out](https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/lomath.htm#alientiles) is called "Alien Tiles", though that normally cycles through four colours instead of just two.