# An array of light-bulbs

Tags: combinatorics, lights-out

There is a grid of 2024 by 2024 light-bulbs. Initially, all bulbs are off.

You can switch the state of all 2024 bulbs in a row simultaneously, or all 2024 bulbs in a column simultaneously, and do this as many times as you want.

Can you reach a state in which all the 2024 bulbs in the main diagonal are on, and all the other bulbs are off?

Comment: The following question is about the same game (but 3x3): [Counter Flipping](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50032/counter-flipping). The answer solves this one too as it characterizes when it can be solved.